# Scheduling tasks in android

Tags: android, service, timer

I have an android service which i want to perform some task at time intervals.I have chosen to use a scheduler.In my on create method of the service i have implemented the scheduler.However,the code inside the scheduler method does not execute.Here is my implementation.,Where am i going wrong?

```
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Share Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    // getSharePrices();
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
            .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getSharePrices();
            checkWatchList();
            Log.i(tag, "Service created...");
            checkWatchList();
        }
    }, 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

When the service is started from within my application,it executes alright.But when started after phone booting by a broadcast receiver it just displays the toast message and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at **CWAC-WakefulIntentService**

When following the instructions from his site you can do something like:

```
        WakefulIntentService.scheduleAlarms(new UpdateStateListener(),
                this, true);
```

and the UpdateStateListener:

```
public class UpdateStateListener implements WakefulIntentService.AlarmListener {

private long oneminute = 1000 * 60; 

public void scheduleAlarms(AlarmManager mgr, PendingIntent pi, Context ctxt) {
    mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+oneminute, oneminute, pi);
}

public void sendWakefulWork(Context ctxt) {
    WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(ctxt, UpdateStateService.class);
}

public long getMaxAge() {
    return oneminute*2;
}
```

}

This example calls the UpdateStateService once every minute.

Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getSharePrices();
            checkWatchList();
            Log.i(tag, "Service created...");
            checkWatchList();
        }
    }, 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

First execute after 5 seconds and further executions every 10 seconds.

Or you can use Timer class